# Raspberry Pi 2 - MsVsMon.exe not running

Tags: windows-iot

I have Raspberry Pi 2 and (am trying to) develop with WIndows IoT Core. I think I have followed all directions at http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/GetStarted.htm. I am using all the latest IoT Core Image and Visual Studio 2015 installs listed by the link.

IoT Core Watcher recongizes my raspberry pi 2
The web interface also allows me to configure the raspberry pi.
but MsVsMon.exe is not running on the raspberry when i list processes.

From a powershell when i try to start MsVsMon i get the following error:

```
[minwinpc]: PS C:\Data\Users\Administrator\Documents> schtasks /run /tn StartMsVsmon
schtasks : ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The syst...file specified.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Because MsVsMon is not running i am not able to debug from Visual Studio.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, and there is a very simple fix!

If you are trying to deploy the app with the authentication mode "None", change it to "Universal (unencrypted protocol)". That was required since the November update to IoT and Visual Studio Update 1.

You can find the authentication mode in Properties -> Debug -> Authentication Mode, at least for a C# app.

Comment: This fix ended up working, in a sense - I'm working on a node.js app that broke after I updated Iot-Core to the November update. It wouldn't even allow me to configure this kind of auth to allow VS to deploy the debugging exe so I had to deploy a random C# Universal App (configured as described above), then kill it. After that msvmon was available and I was able to start it from the IoT-core device's debugging page.

Comment: I tried all mentioned above, but I still have same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723792/failed-to-connect-to-device-192-168-1-17-using-universal-authentication