# msvsmon.exe not running on Windows iot

Tags: windows-iot

I have updated my Raspberry PI 2 with the latest version of Windows iot and since then i have issues with getting remote debug to work. What i think is the problem is that msvsmon.exe not is running. I have tryed to reinstall windows, but it's the same problem.

I have seen this on MS site, but there is no solution to the problem

> To be able to deploy applications from Visual Studio 2015, you will need to make sure the Visual Studio Remote Debugger is running on your Windows IoT Core device. The remote debugger should launch automatically at machine boot time. To double check, use the tlist command to list all the running processes from powershell. There should be two instances of msvsmon.exe running on the device.

I have been googling and search on this site, but so far i dont have any luck
I have found this answer here in this forum, but it did not work for me.
[Raspberry Pi 2 - MsVsMon.exe not running](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39407/raspberry-pi-2-msvsmon-exe-not-running)

Answer (score 1):

hmm, the answer is rather simple....
Just install Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 :)
[Some info about that....](http://embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones/entryid/721/Win-10-IoT-Core-Visual-Studio-2015-Update-1-App-Deployment-and-Debug-Requirements)

Comment: I have update 3, but I have similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723792/failed-to-connect-to-device-192-168-1-17-using-universal-authentication